# Where can I find my companions in Act 3?

Tags: warhammer-40k-rogue-trader

In Act 3, you start split from your party members and they need to be re-recruited. Where can I find them in the city of Commarragh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, three important events affect the availability of places and companions:

- Talking with the Malice in the Pit - will give you access to the Mangled Sector to deal with the Commisar
- Winning the first fight in the Arena will give you access to the Anatomical Opera
- Winning the second fight should give you access to all the rest

About the locations (from my personal experience and things that I've glimpsed on the web)L

- Abelard is in the Mangled Sector
- Argenta is near the Commisar in the Mangled Sector
- Yrliet is near the entrance to the Pit (where previously you were evading some drukhari), but only after you agree to kill the Commissar
- Pasqal is near the elevator to the Magled Sector but is only available after the first fight in the arena
- Idira is in the Anatomical Opera, in the far end behind the haemonculi. For me, she was available after the first fight.
- Jae is available after the first fight, near the entrance to Opera
- Heinrix and Cassia are also in the opera (near the entrance) but might be available only after the second fight.

Availability time might change depending on your party composition, but the locations should be the same.